# Quick little problem with mod_rewrite (and Joomla if relevant)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

For the sake of roll-back-ability I've pushed a newer version of a Joomla project into a sub-directory (`sandbox`) of the existing site.

(*We moved them from 1.0 to 1.5*)

To open up the newly uploaded version for public access, I figured I would just add an `.htaccess` file to the existing documents root, to skip over the files therein:

```
+- /www
    +- index.php     # old version
    +- ...           # files
    |
    +- .htaccess     # htaccess file for redirects
    |
    +- /sandbox
        +- index.php # new version
        +- ...       # files
```

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
# .htaccess for sandbox redirect

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sandbox/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sandbox/$1 [L]
```

It "*works*", and `http://mysite.com` now displays the contents of the sandbox directory; **however** links within the new version of the site include `sandbox` in their URLs, which still work of course, but now we have `http://mysite.com/sandbox/foo/bar` happenening, when we only want `http://mysite.com/foo/bar`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not move the old site to /oldsite and move the new site to the root? If you've tested it and the site works, there is no need to mess around with all the redirecting.

Comment: Thought my way would prove to be simpler; however, I ended up re-organizing the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set property $live_site in configuration.php in your joomla directory to "http://mysite.com"